# How do you get inline code/text highlighting within a Jira ticket?

Tags: jira

I am trying go find an option that does `this` kind of highlighting that is quick/easy to use within a Jira ticket. The links below I have read through. I don't want to use a `{code}` bracket every time I want to highlight a keyword or attribute to pay attention to ie:

`schema.tableName.myColumn = true`.

You can easily do this within Microsoft Teams, Discord if you are having trouble understanding what I am looking for. Is there anything else that is in the works or currently out there for the Jira community to use? Something as easy as using tick marks?

**Resources Viewed:**

[Using a `{code}` block](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Highlighting-code-within-a-code-block/qaq-p/20181)

[Highlighting words with `<style>`](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Highlight-words-in-confluence-text-editor/qaq-p/226033)

[Code Block Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/code-block-macro-139390.html)

Answer (score 7):

**Closest** to this, out of the box is the `{{monospaced}}` formatting. Just enclose the text with double curly quotes `{{`,`}}`. No fancy syntax highlighting though. See Jira's [Wiki Style Renderer guide](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=texteffects).

If you like, you could also try this plugin [Markin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1214558/markin-markdown-for-jira-cloud-server?hosting=cloud&tab=overview).